# let U be a set which is both closed and open

Tags: general-topology

prove or disprove

Let (X,T ) be a topological space and let U be a set that is both closed and open. Then Int(Cl(U)) = Cl(Int(U)).

I think it is true statement ,I am stuck on "let U be a set that is both closed and open" I do not know what means exactly and does it affect my prove ?

my proof

since U is both open and closed then Cl(U)=U and Int(U)=U

Hence ,Int(U) = Cl(U)=U.

Is it right ?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: You have only shown that $\operatorname{Int}(U) = \operatorname{Cl}(U)$, not that $\operatorname{Int}(\operatorname{Cl}(U)) = \operatorname{Cl}(\operatorname{Int}(U))$.

Comment: because Cl(U)=U and Int(U)=U

Answer (score 1):

It indeed means that $U$ is open and $U$ is closed as well. This can surely happen for some sets $U$ ("sets are not doors, they can be open and closed at the same time", as a teacher of mine once said).

So indeed $\operatorname{Int}(U) = U = \operatorname{Cl}(U)$ for this $U$ and so indeed $\operatorname{Int}(\operatorname{Cl}(U)) = \operatorname{Int}(U) = U$ an similarly for the other order. There is no more to it than that.